# When Rendered In Cycles Lamps Seem To Disappear

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

When I render there seems to be no lighting in the scene.

Here's a link to download the files

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4y9dqUn871TdnhGVzg3czFGY2s

[image: Picture of Problem]

Comment: Check your objects visibility and renderability in the outliner

Comment: If there were no lights it would be black, it looks more like you need to turn up the lights to make it brighter.

Answer (score 3):

An area lamp in your scene is [restricted from rendering](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/outliner.html#object-level-restrictions).

1. Open an outliner.
2. Select the lamp with the Render icon turned off and enable rendering. [image]

[image]